# Trying to keep arrow element rotated while hovering over a header

Tags: css

I'm trying to create an arrow icon for my navigation links in the header of my website, and I want it to work so that when you hover over the navigation link, and the menu drops down, an arrow icon to the right of it will go from an upright (0 deg) position, to a down (180) deg position. When I stop hovering the direct header title, and go to the dropdown list, the arrow immediately resets to a 0 degree position. How should I make it so then when the cursor is in the menu, the arrow stays down?

```
.header-nav-folder-title:after {   
content: '\F107'; 
font-family: FontAwesome;
display: inline-block;
padding-left: 4px;
  padding-right: 6px;
  padding-top: 3px;
transform:rotate(0deg)};


.header-nav-folder-title:hover::after{
  transition: transform 0.2s;
  transform:rotate(180deg)};
```

Comment: Can you provide your HTML structure for the dropdown button with the arrow

Comment: <a href="/cooking-classes">
                <span class="header-nav-folder-item-content">
                  Cooking Classes
                </span>
              </a>

Comment: Please provide the complete HTML related to the button `.header-nav-folder-title` including the arrow or just simply provide the HTML of the header if its not too much.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.